# Set intervals for x-axis in Scatter plot in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I m trying to set the x-axis interals as

```
2016/02/01
2016/02/15
2016/03/01
2016/03/15
2016/04/01
2016/04/15
```

ie. 2 weeks interval as x axis.
But the code that i have written is not setting it properly. When i run the code i get

2016/02/01
2016/03/22
2016/05/11

```
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("UserLog!$AC$1:$AD$" & date_no_row)
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 42401
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 42491
        Const iIntervals As Integer = 15
        With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory)
            .MajorUnit = (.MaximumScale - .MinimumScale) / iIntervals
        End With
```

How to set the intervals as 2 weeks?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Following code will set interval as 2 weeks

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory)
        .MinimumScale = "2016/02/01"
        .MaximumScale = "2016/05/15"
        .BaseUnitIsAuto = True
        .MajorUnit = 7
        .MajorUnitScale = xlDays
        .MinorUnitIsAuto = True
        .Crosses = xlAutomatic
        .AxisBetweenCategories = True
        .ReversePlotOrder = False
    End With
End Sub
```